# Cannot parse a PHP generated JSON into a .NET object. Always empty

Tags: asp.net, json, jsonserializer

I have number of PHP generated JSON data. Here is a sample:

```
[{
    "model": "XXXXX",
    "category": "Some Category",
    "description": "Hydrostatic",
    "id": "xyz123",
    "diagram": {
        "type": "Clutch",
        "name": "Clutch",
        "image": {
            "remote_url": "http://example.com/img/1565602310.png",
            "local_name": "diagram.png",
            "width": 919,
            "height": 668
        },
        "parts": [{
            "part": "010",
            "partNumber": "N22-45X",
            "partName": "Super clutch",
            "qty": 1,
            "ic": "",
            "weight": 1.848,
            "coords": {
                "xFrom": 552,
                "yFrom": 540,
                "xTo": 674,
                "yTo": 607
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

I am trying to build a parser in `ASP.NET 5.0 Core`.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "data/data.json");
string strJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

The above core snippet extract the JSON string fine from the file. Now, I am trying to get the JSON converted to an object `ModelData`

```
List<ModelData> md = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ModelData>>(strJson);
List<ModelData> m_data = new List<ModelData>();
```

But it is always empty.

The `ModelData` class looks like following:

```
namespace ColemanData.Models
{
    public class ModelData
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string BookCD { get; set; }
        public Diagram Diagram { get; set; }
        public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }

    }

    public class Diagram
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DiagramImage Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class DiagramImage
    {
        public string RemoteUrl { get; set; }
        public float Width { get; set; }
        public float Height { get; set; }
        public string LocalName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Ic { get; set; }
        public float Weight { get; set; }
        public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coordinates
    {
        public float XStart { get; set; }
        public float YStart { get; set; }
        public float XEnd { get; set; }
        public float YEnd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Taking @sam-sj's idea, I made the following two changes which worked for me.

1. The properties in the class so that they match the keys in the JSON
2. Changed `List<ModelData> md = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ModelData>>(strJson);` to `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelData>>(strJson);`

And now I get the desired object. The `<List<ModelData>>` is required since the JSON is wrapped inside square brackets, i.e. [...], which makes the parser to understand that it is an array.

The modified class now looks like this:

```
public class Image
    {
        public string remote_url { get; set; }
        public string local_name { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coords
    {
        public int xFrom { get; set; }
        public int yFrom { get; set; }
        public int xTo { get; set; }
        public int yTo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public string part { get; set; }
        public string partNumber { get; set; }
        public string partName { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public string ic { get; set; }
        public string pin { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public double lbs { get; set; }
        public Coords coords { get; set; }
    }

    public class Diagram
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public List<Part> parts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string id{ get; set; }
        public Diagram diagram { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the JSON serializer can break the JSON data up into multiple list items like you are trying to do.  I would maybe try creating a new class that represents all the data from the JSON input as a list and then deserialize the entire JSON object as one to this new class.

Comment: Thank you! Would you help me with a sample code or directing me to a similar tutorial please?

Comment: @sam-sjs, thank you for putting me on the right direction. I have updated my post with a working solution!

Comment: Hi @SubrataSarkar, it's good to see you get the correct answer. Meanwhile, please add the solution as **answer** but **not place it in question**  and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun I added the solution as answer. Hope this works! Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @sam-sj's idea, I made the following two changes which worked for me.

1. The properties in the class so that they match the keys in the JSON
2. Changed `List<ModelData> md = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ModelData>>(strJson);` to `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelData>>(strJson);`

And now I get the desired object. The `<List<ModelData>>` is required since the JSON is wrapped inside square brackets, i.e. [...], which makes the parser to understand that it is an array.

The modified class now looks like this:

```
public class Image
    {
        public string remote_url { get; set; }
        public string local_name { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coords
    {
        public int xFrom { get; set; }
        public int yFrom { get; set; }
        public int xTo { get; set; }
        public int yTo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public string part { get; set; }
        public string partNumber { get; set; }
        public string partName { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public string ic { get; set; }
        public string pin { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public double lbs { get; set; }
        public Coords coords { get; set; }
    }

    public class Diagram
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public List<Part> parts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string id{ get; set; }
        public Diagram diagram { get; set; }
    }
```